# Highlight and track changes in Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, windows

I have an Excel file that contains projects and various milestones for each of them. A project is identified by a project number (PNR) which is tracked in column B of the worksheet "Projects". Columns F to I contain various milestones in the format dd-mm-yyyy. My aim is to monitor these milestones and highlight changes in such a way that if a milestone is delayed (the date moves into the future), the cell is highlighted in red. If the milestone is brought forward (date moves closer to today), the cell should be highlighted in green. I also want to display all changes in another worksheet called "Tracking" in the following format "Project *PNR*: *cell xyz* was changed from *date1* to *date2*".

My attempt looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ProjekteSheet As Worksheet
    Dim TrackingSheet As Worksheet
    Dim WatchRange As Range
    Dim ProjekteRange As Range
    Dim Milestone As Range
    Dim ChangeMsg As String
    Dim OldValue As Date
    Dim NewValue As Date
    
    ' Arbeitsblätter festlegen
    Set ProjekteSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projekte")
    Set TrackingSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracking")
    
    ' Überwachungsbereich (Spalten F bis I)
    Set WatchRange = Intersect(Target, ProjekteSheet.Range("F:I"))
    
    ' Überprüfen, ob Änderungen in Überwachungsbereich stattgefunden haben
    If Not WatchRange Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' Ereignisverarbeitung vorübergehend deaktivieren
        
        ' Durchlaufe jede geänderte Zelle
        For Each Milestone In WatchRange
            ' Überprüfen, ob die geänderte Zelle ein gültiges Datum enthält
            If IsDate(Milestone.Value) Then
                OldValue = Milestone.Value
                NewValue = OldValue
                
                ' Vergleich des alten und neuen Datums
                If OldValue > NewValue Then
                    ' Datum wurde nach vorne verschoben (grün hervorheben)
                    Milestone.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' Grün
                    ChangeMsg = "hat sich von " & Format(OldValue, "dd.mm.yyyy") & " auf " & Format(NewValue, "dd.mm.yyyy") & " verschoben."
                ElseIf OldValue < NewValue Then
                    ' Datum wurde nach hinten verschoben (rot hervorheben)
                    Milestone.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Rot
                    ChangeMsg = "hat sich von " & Format(OldValue, "dd.mm.yyyy") & " auf " & Format(NewValue, "dd.mm.yyyy") & " verschoben."
                Else
                    ' Datum wurde nicht geändert (keine Hervorhebung)
                    ChangeMsg = "bleibt unverändert bei " & Format(NewValue, "dd.mm.yyyy") & "."
                End If
                
                ' Protokollieren der Änderung im Tracking-Arbeitsblatt
                With TrackingSheet
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "Zelle " & Milestone.Address & " " & ChangeMsg
                End With
            End If
        Next Milestone
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' Ereignisverarbeitung wieder aktivieren
    End If
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the code does nothing at all. I have spent hours looking for a bug but have found nothing. Could someone please look into this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considerd the "track changes" or Conditional formatting"?

Comment: I'd think you'd need to use `Undo` to get the value before the update - your `OldValue` isn't doing what you think, and in any case its value is lost between individual updates.